# Traduction de "This is not about making ..."

Tags: traduction

> This is not about making people's lives better. This is only about enriching you and your friends.

Comment traduire ça en français ?

> Ça n'a rien à voir avec améliorer les vies des gens. Ça a seulement à voir avec vous enrichir et enrichir vos amis.

En particulier, "améliorer" est-il la forme correcte du verbe après "avec" ?

Comment: Also: « Il n'est pas question de », « Il ne s'agit pas de »

Comment: Ou la forme impersonnelle "On ne parle pas de... (rendre  la vie des autres meilleure.)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je ne traduirais pas *"This is not about"* par *"Ça n'a rien à voir avec"*. Ce n'est pas parce que ce n'est pas le sujet que ça n'a rien à voir, c'est le même genre de nuance qu'entre *"I'm not hungry"* et *"I'm full"*.

Je traduirais cette idée par la notion de *"but"*:

> Le but n'est pas d'améliorer la vie des gens. Le but est tout simplement de s'enrichir, toi et tes amis.

Ou même, contracté:

> Le but n'est pas d'améliorer la vie des gens, mais tout simplement de s'enrichir, toi et tes amis.

On peut également remplacer "but" par "Objectif", ou "Idée" selon le contexte.

---

Pour la forme d'*améliorer*: Pour être correct, il faudrait dire:

> Ça n'a rien à voir avec le fait d'améliorer les vies des gens.

Car "Avoir quelque chose à voir avec" attend un groupe nominal ou un nom (ou un pronom), pas un verbe.

Comment: "Car améliorer attend un nom, pas un verbe." Qu'est que tu veux dire ici?

Comment: @user11550 Hé bien, on met un nom après "avoir a voir avec", pas un verbe, mais je me suis trompé, j'ai mis le mauvais verbe.

Comment: Nous dirions pourtant facilement : `ça n'a rien à voir avec le fait d'améliorer la vie des gens`  même si l'action en question conduit à une amélioration de la vie des gens .. et ceci pour préciser que l'amélioration éventuelle n'est qu'une conséquence induite, qui n'est pas nécessairement désirée ...

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington Oui, c'est ce que j'ai voulu faire comprendre dans mon premier paragraphe, et par l'emploi de `but`.

Comment: Il y a une incohérence de pronoms dans *..de s'enrichir, toi et tes amis*, j'écrirais plutôt: *mais tout simplement de **vous** enrichir, toi et tes amis.* ou éventuellement *...de s'enrichir, **pour** toi et tes amis.*